# Swift IOS - Using UIPickerView AND Keyboard

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

In my app when user clicks on UITextField he should be able to pick up a value from UIPickerView OR enter his own value using keyboard.

What's the best way of doing it in terms of user experience and ease of implementation?

UIPickerView with toolbar is already implemented.

I'd appreciate both advice on best way of doing it and example code of switching keyboard <-> pickerview.

I've tried adding a button "Show keyboard" on pickerview's toolbar and adding the following code:

```
func showKeyboard() {
    selectedTextField.inputView = nil
}
```

But clicking this button doesn't do anything. Also I'm not sure it's a good way in terms of UX.

Comment: After setting inputView to nil, try selectedTextField.resignFirstResponder() then selectedTextField.becomeFirstResponder()

Comment: Thanks @Tobias, I've just tried resignFirstResponder, becomeFirstResponder and inputView = nil in all possible orders and it doesn't pull up keyboard in any of them.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution:

```
var useKeyboard:Bool = true
func showKeyboard() {
    if useKeyboard {
        useKeyboard = false
        selectedTextField.inputView = nil
        selectedTextField.reloadInputViews()
        selectedTextField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearance.Default
        selectedTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.Default
    } else {
        useKeyboard = true
        selectedTextField.inputView = nil
        selectedTextField.reloadInputViews()
        createPicker(selectedTextField)
        selectedTextField.resignFirstResponder()
        selectedTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}

// That's my custom picker - adjust whatever you need
func createPicker(sender: UITextField){
    selectedTextField = sender

    // Create picker view
    var newPickerView: UIPickerView
    newPickerView = UIPickerView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 200, view.frame.width, 300))
    newPickerView.backgroundColor = .whiteColor()

    // Only for UIPickerView
    newPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = true
    newPickerView.delegate = self
    newPickerView.dataSource = self

    // Create toolbar
    var toolBar = UIToolbar()
    toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
    toolBar.translucent = true
    toolBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 76/255, green: 217/255, blue: 100/255, alpha: 1)
    toolBar.sizeToFit()

    // Create buttons
    var doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "donePicker")
    var spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    var cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "cancelPicker")
    var customButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Keyboard", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "showKeyboard")

    // Assign buttons to toolbar
    toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, customButton, doneButton], animated: false)
    toolBar.userInteractionEnabled = true

    // Add pickerview and toolbar to textfield
    sender.inputView = newPickerView
    sender.inputAccessoryView = toolBar
}
func donePicker() {
    useKeyboard = true
    selectedTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}
func cancelPicker() {
    useKeyboard = true
    selectedTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```